# Expandable panel pushes column down on tablet devices

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

I am experience an issue with my layout on tablet devices.

Currently building a video hosting website - each row contains 4 sections, on tablet devices I am using col-sm-6 - this then displays 2 of the items on a row.

Each item has an expandable panel at the bottom of it.

When on tablet devices, when I expand the first item on the left, it then pushes the column below down.

I am wondering if there is anyway of preventing this?

Please see screenshot below:

[image: Column breaking on tablet devices]

Codepen: http://codepen.io/shane309/pen/wWWjBM

The code is as follows:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
<h1>Animated Videos</h1>
</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="hovereffect" onclick="void(0)">
                <img src="images/animated-video-1.jpg" alt="Animated Video 1 Preview" class="img-responsive videoThumbnail" />
                <div class="overlay">
                   <h2>Animated Video #1</h2>
                   <a class="info" href="animated-video-2.html">WATCH NOW</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
            <h3 class="videoTitle">LMS Explainer</h3>
            <p class="featuredText">Quisque rhoncus, nunc ac rhoncus pellentesque. </p>
            <p class="read-more"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#animated-video-1" class="collapsed">Read More</a></p>
            <div id="animated-video-1" class="collapse">
            <p class="expandedText">Praesent quis erat non leo pulvinar luctus. Etiam vitae enim blandit, aliquam eros ut, euismod libero.</p>
            </div>   
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="hovereffect" onclick="void(0)">
                <img src="images/animated-video-2.jpg" alt="Animated Video 1 Preview" class="img-responsive videoThumbnail" />
                <div class="overlay">
                   <h2>Animated Video #2</h2>
                   <a class="info" href="animated-video-3.html">WATCH NOW</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
            <h3 class="videoTitle">Positive Psychology #1</h3>
            <p class="featuredText">Donec id odio nulla. Vivamus pretium sagittis sem in elementum.</p>
            <p class="read-more"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#animated-video-2" class="collapsed">Read More</a></p>
            <div id="animated-video-2" class="collapse">
            <p class="expandedText">Sed gravida magna sit amet mollis bibendum. Praesent vel augue ornare, rutrum augue eget, laoreet libero. Etiam vitae magna lectus.</p>
            </div>     
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="hovereffect" onclick="void(0)">
                <img src="images/animated-video-3.jpg" alt="Animated Video 1 Preview" class="img-responsive videoThumbnail" />
                <div class="overlay">
                   <h2>Animated Video #3</h2>
                   <a class="info" href="animated-video-4.html">WATCH NOW</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
            <h3 class="videoTitle">Positive Psychology #2</h3>
            <p class="featuredText">Morbi aliquet quam sed enim dictum, eu ultricies dui cursus.</p>
            <p class="read-more"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#animated-video-3" class="collapsed">Read More</a></p>
            <div id="animated-video-3" class="collapse">
            <p class="expandedText">Duis a augue ac felis semper ultrices at quis mauris. Morbi id velit eu lacus fermentum efficitur non eget lacus. Proin volutpat est et quam congue hendrerit.</p>
            </div>   
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="hovereffect" onclick="void(0)">
                <img src="images/animated-video-4.jpg" alt="Animated Video 1 Preview" class="img-responsive videoThumbnail" />
                <div class="overlay">
                   <h2>Animated Video #4</h2>
                   <a class="info" href="animated-video-5.html">WATCH NOW</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
            <h3 class="videoTitle">Interactive Video Explainer</h3>
            <p class="featuredText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
            <p class="read-more"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#animated-video-4" class="collapsed">Read More</a></p>
            <div id="animated-video-4" class="collapse">
            <p class="expandedText">Phasellus luctus tortor ut quam volutpat condimentum. Nunc nec felis finibus, pharetra lacus a, aliquam ante.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your second div (the Psychology one) add this line:

```
 <div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Add more clearfix divs just after any div that's preventing the successive div from lining up properly.

Comment: The simplest solution is the most effective!
I created a new class so it only clears the float on tablet devices - works like an absolute charm! 

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: You don't need to create a class! Bootstrap has one for you:
<div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div>

Comment: ah perfect :) I'm still a novice when it comes to Bootstrap. Thanks again!

Comment: @ShanePrice feel free to upvote if this answer helped ;)

Comment: I'm still a StackOverflow newbie so I'm afraid I can't just yet :(

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the first section which has more height than the second section. You have to set the maximum height of the section to other sections height.

Option 1:
Set min-height to the section using css

```
section { min-height: 300px } //set height depending upon ur need
```

Option 2: using jquery for dynamic content

```
 var maxheight;
    $('section').each(function(){
    var currHeight = $(this).height();
    if(maxHeight < currHeight) {
    maxHeight = currHeight;
    }
    });
    if(window.width() < 768) {
    $('section').height(maxHeight);
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I first of all looked at the min-height method using CSS but found this wasn't the best for the design.


I have gone with Option 2, but unfortunately cannot get it to work correctly. I've amended the videos sections to include the following class:

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 videoSection">

I then amended the script to match my class, but unfortunately this isn't working.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
         var maxHeight;
            $("#videoSection").each(function(){
            var currHeight = $(this).height();
            if(maxHeight < currHeight) {
            maxHeight = currHeight;
            }
            });
            if(window.width() < 992) {
            $("#videoSection").height(maxHeight);
            }
      </script>

Comment: In html you are adding class (videoSection) and In jquery, u are adding ID. Please add the jquery plugin before and place that code inside `$(function(){  var maxHeight; $(".videoSection").each(function(){ var currHeight = $(this).height(); if(maxHeight < currHeight) { maxHeight = currHeight; } }); if(window.width() < 992) { $(".videoSection").height(maxHeight); }  })`

Comment: I'm currently working on adding this to a codepen. Will update once complete.